# I've entered the Schengen area as a tourist. Do I need to re-enter the Schengen in order to activate my working holiday visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, working-visas

I am from New Zealand and hold a new Zealand passport. I have a working holiday visa for Germany starting on the 16-10-16 ending 15-10-17.

I plan on entering Germany on 19-8-16 on a 90 day tourist visa.  I have flights booked for the 14-10-16 to London and returning to Germany on 16-10-16 to enter on my one year working holiday visa.

Is this possible to do this, and do I have to leave the Schengen zone for a certain period of time to re enter on my work visa (I've heard it has to be more than 24 hours)

Comment: The part about leaving the zone and returning to activate your WH visa is fine. The question being  when you first arrive in August you want to enter as a short stay visitor under the 90/180 rule, are you asking if they will admit you as a visitor when you have an existing category "D" visa?

Comment: I know about other change-of-visa-status situations when border-hopping was not necessary to "activate" the new visa. Does anybody know for sure? Perhaps the people on Expatriates SE can help.

Comment: You don't need to leave the Schengen area, hence I've updated your question. Also this would work better on our sister Expats.SE website.